# What is the thread/screw size for the iRobot Create 2 internal screw bosses described in the Open Interface Spec doc

Tags: irobot-create

In the “[iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf)” provided for the iRobot Create 2, there is a section titled “Roomba Internal Screw Boss Locations”.  It states that “Screws may be replaced with threaded standoffs.”

Does anyone know what screw/thread size of standoffs should be used to match the screw threads?

(I saw another similar thread but the only solution listed was to re-thread the holes, which I would like to avoid if at all possible.)

Thanks!

Comment: Take a photo of the screw with a ruler, preferably both in mm and inches.

Comment: FYI, the OI Spec document has now been updated with more specifics on the threaded standoffs.  See page 6.

Answer (score 1):

If it says it can be replaced with "threaded standoffs" then it is probably referring to the same kind of [threaded standoffs used in computer cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws), so probably 6-32 (most likely) or M3.

Answer (score 1):

The screws that Roomba uses are special for going into plastic.  They are very similar to a #4 sheet metal screw.  So I don't think you are going to match the thread size exactly, but it doesn't matter.  As long as you don't plan on screwing and unscrewing the screws which will wear out the bosses.  Pretty much any screw with the right diameter will work because you are only going into plastic.  A #4 machine screw also works well.